# How do I add mulitipile preprocessing functions to a DataGenerator in keras?

Tags: keras

I have a a training DataGenerator with a preprocessing function (could be InceptionV3's,ResNet50's etc. preprocess input) as follows:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        preprocessing_function = preprocess_input,
        rotation_range=30,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        shear_range=0,
        brightness_range= [0.5,1.0],
        zoom_range=0.1,
        channel_shift_range=10,
        vertical_flip=True,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        fill_mode='nearest')
```

And now I want to add another preprocessing function:

```
get_random_eraser(v_l=0, v_h=1, pixel_level=False)
```

So all in all it would chain the model's preprocessing functions (as it was pretrained in keras) and implement another preprocessing function. How do I do that? (preprocessing_function can't get a list [f1, f2], and I cannot repeat preprocessing_function declaration in a new line(makes sense, but tried that anyway))

Comment: I really don't understand the question. Isn't it just create a new `ImageDataGenerator`?

Comment: @DanielMöller , why new? I want to have 2 preprocessing function in the same datagen.

Comment: IIRC you can provide a list of DataGenerators to the training call? // If not you can always make a custom DataGenerator and use the two pre-made ones within.

Comment: How will you choose which function to use?

Comment: @DanielMöller , I don't want to choose, I want to use both of them.

Comment: @KDecker what's the simplest  way to do that in keras? Can you give a short example?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new generator with your custom function:

```
def custom_function(input_image):
    input_image = preprocess_input(input_image)
    return get_random_eraser(v_l=0, v_h=1, pixel_level=False)(input_image)

new_train_gen = train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    preprocessing_function = custom_function,
    rotation_range=30,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0,
    brightness_range= [0.5,1.0],
    zoom_range=0.1,
    channel_shift_range=10,
    vertical_flip=True,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest')
```

It may be interesting to add a `print(input_image.shape)` inside the `custom_function` in the first attempt just to make sure whether `input_image` is a single image or a batch. You may need to adjust your inner functions accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, it looks ok. Thanks!